# determine if the sequence increases, decreases, or neither

Tags: analysis

determine if the sequence increases, decreases, or neither:

{$e^{-n}$}

This is what I have:

$f^{'}$(n)= -$e^{-n}$

u= -n du= -1

d/du ($e^{u}$)= $e^{u}$ d/dx(-n)

$e^{u}$(-1)= -$e^{-n}$

-$e^{-n}$=0

$e^{-n}$=0

-$e^{-0}$= -1 which is negative so the sequence decreases

Is there another method to do this if so how else could I have done it?

Comment: You could say $2<e<3.$ So $2^{-n}>e^{-n}>3^{-n}$. Since $m^{-n}>m^{-n-1}$  for $m=2,3$ it must be that $\{e^{-n}\}$ is decreasing.

Comment: What do you mean $-e^{-n}$=0?

Answer (score 1):

Simplicity.

$e^{-n} > 0$ and $0< \frac 1e <1$

so $e^{-(n+1)} = e^{-n}\cdot \frac 1e < e^{-n}$.

So it is decreasing.

Comment: When you wrote $1<{1 \over e},$ did you mean $0<{1 \over e}$?

Comment: Of course I did.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(n) = e^{-n}
$$

A sequence is decreasing iff. for all $n, m \in \mathbb N$, $n < m$ implies $f(n) > f(m)$. Indeed, this is the case here, $f(n) / f(m) = e^{-n - (-m)} = e^{m - n} > e^0 = 1$, so $f(n) > f(m)$.